# Why do I get an error message when installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore through NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 1.1.2

---

> GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/index.json
>   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/index.json
>   924ms Restoring packages for C:\Users\Usr\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Prj10\Prj10\Prj10.csproj... Install-Package :
>   Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 is not compatible with
>   netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 supports: portable-net 45+win8
>   (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7) At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 1.1.2
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   Install-Package : Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0 is not
>   compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0 supports: portable-net 45+win8
>   (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7) At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 1.1.2
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   Install-Package : One or more packages are incompatible with
>   .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 1.1.2
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes
>   for 'IslamQA'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 1.1.2
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: What is your project type, .net core? And what is your Visual Studio version? I can install this package to my .net core project with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2(26430.6). please check your Visual Studio 2017 version.

Comment: .net core is my project type

Comment: It`s works fine on my machine with a blank .net core project. Not sure this issue whether this issue is related to your VS version, the project itself or others. So could you please try to update your VS to latest version, then create a blank project to install the package, check if it works fine? if not, please share us a sample so that we could reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in the error message.  It appears that some packages are not compatible with the profile you have picked.  Make sure you choose a version of the packages that are, or that you change the profile you are using.

Here are the items from the error messages:

> Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 is not compatible with
>   netcoreapp1.1  Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0 supports:
>   portable-net 45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
>
> One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1

It appears that the EntityFrameworkCore depends on a version of CodeAnalysus.CSharp that is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1.  It appears to require the full netstandard1.3 profile